# Read excel sheet data and put on a text view in android studio

Tags: android, excel, textbox

I  know how to read an excel sheet in android, but now I want to put the data from  that excel sheet into the text box by clicking a button. I did this after reading the excel sheet.But unformatted symbols are on the text box when i clicked the button.I just want to display the data on the excel sheet on the text box.I searched this every where but I didn't find. Can I do this? If so how?

(I used jxl.jar to read the excel sheet.)

Comment: You know how to read an excel file. Ok. What are you reading from an excel file that you cannot put in a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to get the data from your excel sheet, it is quite simple to put it into a `TextView` when a `Button` is clicked.

First, cast your `Button`. This means linking the button from your layout to the one in your code. Do so like this;

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MY_BUTTON);
```

Of course, you can change the name from `myButton` to whatever you like (but it must remain the same name throughout), and `MY_BUTTON` must be the same id as the button in your layout.

Next, you set an `OnClickListener`. This listens out for when the button is clicked, as the name indicates. In your `OnClickListener`, you will cast your `TextView` (almost the same as what we did with the button, but for a different thing), and set the text to it. See below:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MY_TEXTVIEW);
        // Again, 'myText' can be changed to what you want - it needs to be the same consistently
        // and 'MY_TEXTVIEW' must be the same id as the one in your layout XML file  

        // Now, we set the text to your data
        myText.setText(YOUR_DATA);

        // 'YOUR_DATA' is the data that you want to display in the TextView              
    }
});
```

Comment: I already did this. But after clicking the button in my text box there are some symbols that unclear for me.. no data on the text box. But when i read a text file then all the things in the text file comes to the text box. I think the wrong is with the format.

Comment: Problem is i am unable to post a screen shot for this as i haven't 10 reputations :(